# Auto fire anchor tag on page load

Tags: jquery, html

In my code I have an anchor tag which contains a dial number 
`<a id="clickit" href="tel:+9190000000">Call me at +9190000000</a>`

I want it so when a page loads it will fire the a tag automatically, I was trying to do that though but it failed. Below is my code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#clickit').click();
    });
</script>
```

Can anyone help me to see where I have gone wrong?

Comment: You probably can't do this because your browser stops the website from automatically making calls...

Comment: You can just get the property `href` of your anchor tag and assign to `$(window).location.href` inside the `ready` function.

Comment: so there is no way? I JUST WANT WHEN SOMEONE OPEN THE WEBSITE the dial option will be fetched auto

Comment: @DmitryS. can you please explain ?

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution.

Change your script to:

```
<script>
        $(window).on( "load", function() {
            window.location.href = $('#clickit').attr('href');
        });
</script>
```

let me know if it works! 
You can test it here:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a id="clickit" href="tel:+9190000000">Call me at +9190000000</a>

<script>
        $(window).on( "load", function() {
            window.location.href = $('#clickit').attr('href');
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple! just run below script...

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#clickit')[0].click();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code:

```
<script>
$(window).load(function(){
    $("#clickit")[0].click();
});
</script>
```

Hope it helps you.